# Tag a tibcoBW ear file created in Jenkins Workspace to SVN

Tags: svn, ant

I'm building ear for a tibco business works project in Jenkins using ANT scripts. Is it possible to tag/add the generated ear present in Jenkins Workspace to SVN?

Answer (score 0):

`svn help import`

With importing, you can add any object from any (even unversioned) location to any part of repository. import will create additional commit in target repository

If you want to have fully automated adding, you must to use `-m` options (of `-F`) in order to specify commit message in command-line

On importing single-file you must also define full path to file in URL in order to get expected result

```
>svn import error.PNG file:///Z:/Repo/tags/1.1/error.png -m "File added"
Adding  (bin)  error.PNG

Committed revision 3.

>svn ls file:///Z:/Repo/tags/1.1/
error.png
```

compare with result of importing the same single file into `file:///Z:/Repo/tags/1.0/` URL

```
>svn log -q -v -r2 file:///Z:/Repo/
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2 | Badger | 2015-10-12 21:01:58 +0500 (Пн, 12 окт 2015)
Changed paths:
   A /tags/1.0
```

1.0 **is file** with name of trailing part of import-URL

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to add your ear file.  In general derived artifacts shouldn't be added to source control.  Your repo will get huge if you add all your ear files.  Since you can recreate any version from source you needn't commit them.

You could have jenkins tag the source at that revision, but tagging every build may generate a lot of noise. You likely want to only tag the interesting versions (the ones you release)